# Woocommerce show individual variations on a page

Tags: woocommerce, variable-product

My woocommerce store sells books for which there are often several variations - ebook, audiobook, paperback...

I have these set up as variable products. But I would like to add pages where people can see just a single variation - so, all the audiobooks or all the ebooks. This would be linked from a menu.

Is this possible? Or should I just give up and do each one as a simple product? I know there are paid plugins out there, but my turnover is super small and I don't want to make a loss on my store.

I've picked up some understanding of code, but programming is not my thing. If you are kind enough to post something, I will need a teensy bit of hand-holding. So saying that I need to target the shop loop (or something) will leave me floundering. But saying, here is some code, just change X for your variation name and add the css or post in functions.php will be set me on the right path.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is duable with custom templates and loop. One question tho after the loop you want ppl to add directly to cart the specific variation or go to the product and select the option ?

Comment: Hi Martin - after the loop, I would like to add directly to cart the specific variation.

This happens when you add a single variation in linked products, so it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new template in your active theme. In my case i named it template-audiobook-products.php - Read more about templates here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
2. Inside the template add the follwoing code

/*
Template Name: Audio books
*/

```
get_header('shop');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', 
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
             'field'    => 'slug',
             'terms'    => 'variable', 
         ),
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_color', //Change to proper attribute
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'blue', //Change to proper value
        ),

     ),
     'fields' => 'ids'

);
$get_all_variable_products = get_posts($args);

$product_ids_list = array();
foreach($get_all_variable_products as $parent_variation_id):
    $_product = wc_get_product($parent_variation_id);
    $variable_product_ids = $_product->get_children();
    foreach($variable_product_ids as $variable_product_id):
        $_variable_product = wc_get_product($variable_product_id);
        $_variable_product_attributes = $_variable_product->get_attributes();
        if($_variable_product_attributes['pa_color'] == 'blue'):
            $product_ids_list[] = array( 'parent_id'=> $parent_variation_id, 'variation_id' => $variable_product_id);
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
woocommerce_product_loop_start();
foreach($product_ids_list as $_product_id):
    //Since $product is obj we can pass it and use our default content-product template.
    $product = wc_get_product($_product_id['variation_id']);
    //Keep in mind this template by default doesnt support ajax (use css to hide button or use woo hook/filters)
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product');
  
    //In case we want custom design or ajax button uncomment following.
    // echo '<a href="?add-to-cart='.$product['variation_id'].'" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="'.$product['variation_id'].'" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>';
endforeach;
woocommerce_product_loop_end();
get_footer('shop');
```

3. Create new page and select this template

To work properly the standart woocommerce template we need to include the classes and other html tags that we may need in our template. Add this function in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function my_custom_body_class($classes) {
    if(is_page_template('template-audiobook-products.php')) {
    $classes[] = 'woocommerce';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','my_custom_body_class');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this code. I suspect this will be a modification too far. But before I decide to abandon the idea completely - what is change to proper attribute and proper value? What do they refer to?

Comment: A new day and a new stab at it - I have added the template within the theme (had to add <?php at the beginning).
Can you explain what I need to change in the code? Such as:
     'taxonomy' => 'pa_color', //Change to proper attribute'terms'    => 'blue', //Change to proper value

Comment: Also, these items are repeated in square brackets. Presumably I also change these. Do I keep or remove the square brackets?

If I want to use the custom design option you have added at the bottom, what do I need to change in the code for this to be activated. Presumably, I have to delete something?

Comment: Change pa_color to the attribute you need and change the term you are looking for. Also change the attribute and term at this line -  if($_variable_product_attributes['pa_color'] == 'blue'): . For custom design you can change the template you want to load wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product'); . Keep in mind this template have to be in your theme woocommerce forlder read more here - https://shorturl.at/atU13 . Another way is to remove wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product'); and echo the data you want from the product such as $product->get_name(); read more  https://shorturl.at/hXZ69

Comment: HI Martin - thanks very much for your efforts.
I managed to work out what attribute and value is - they refer to the things that you enter in the variable product section in the backend of woocommerce (for many people, something like "Colour" (attribute) and then "blue" or "red" (value). After adding these, they are no longer referred to as attribute and value, hence my confusion!
I added the audiobook template page using this code and suddenly I have a page featuring all the ebook boxsets (no audiobooks!). Huh?
Oh well, I guess it kinda works. I'm sure I could fix it with a bit of thought.

Comment: My biggest problem with this method is, it loses the styling of the rest of the site. So even if I got it to display the right things, it would look all wrong.
I have decided I will have to set up variable products for the main shop page and have additional simple products for the audiobook & ebook. When I get to do paperbacks, this may be a bit of an issue with regards to stock levels and the SKU, but it'll have to do for now.
Meanwhile, I hope this code helps someone else. Thanks again!

Comment: You have to just include your proper html that wraps your products in your shop page or category page try adding before your loop this woocommerce_product_loop_start(); and after the loop this woocommerce_product_loop_end(); . I have updated my answer also you need to include woocommerce classes to your body classes.