# Display specific variation products as individual products on a new page using a shortcode in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to display only a specific variation of all my products on a page using a shortcode. In my example, I want to display all the variation products with the attribute "color" and the term "blue" as single product.

Here's my code:

```
function filterVariations() {
    $query = new \WP_Query( 
        array(
        'post_parent' => '', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product_variation',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => 
            array( 
                array(
                'key' => 'attribute_pa_color',
                'value' => 'blue',
                ) 
            ),
        ) 
    );
    
    $result = array();
    if($query->have_posts()){
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->next_post();
            $result[] = $query->post;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    return $result;
}


function custom_variations_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); 
    
    $variations = filterVariations(); 
    if (!empty($variations)) {
        
    // Set loop properties
    //wc_set_loop_prop('columns', 3);
        
    echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();    
        
        foreach ($variations as $variation) {       
           setup_postdata($variation); 
           wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');                  
        }
        
        woocommerce_product_loop_end(); 
    echo '</div>';
        
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
    } else {
        echo 'No variations found.';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_variations', 'custom_variations_shortcode');
```

Here come the problems:

- The displayed products all have the page title as the product title, which is linked to the same page
- The woocommerce styles are not correctly applied (eg. texts are not centered, etc.)
- The 'add to cart' button link is more articulated than necessary: http://localhost/mysite-local/wordpress/books/book-title/?attribute_pa_color=blue&variation_id=188&add-to-cart=186

I think that the main culprit could be this part
`wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');`
but I cannot find a way to probarly fix this.

Is this the correct approach for displaying variation products as single product on a page or are there better solutions?

Comment: You are trying to use the default template for something that is partial using it. I would recommend creating new template for these products otherwise you need to overwrite all hooks in the default template.

Comment: @Snuffy I tried to use a new template (following this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317810/woocommerce-show-individual-variations-on-a-page), but I got the same problem: the products displayed have the page title and not the product title

Comment: Can you clarify where you get this title  ? Screenshot or smth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule on stack overflow is one problem at the time, so I will answer here your first problem around the product variation title:

The following code will replace the product title, for product type "variation", with the correct title to be displayed:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'adjust_shop_loop_item_title', 5 );
function adjust_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
        add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_variation_title', 10 );
    }
}

function woocommerce_template_loop_variation_title() {
    global $product;

    echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</h2>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested Storefront theme and work on most themes.

> Some themes already made changes to products and enable sometimes custom hooks. In that case, if the code doesn't work, you will need to search in the main theme files for `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` to find out what are those changes, and how to manage making the required changes to my code, to make it work.

---

I have tested your code in a new page, pasting `[custom_variations]` shortcode in the editor, and I don't have any styling problems or glitches.

For the variation add to cart link, is completely normal and Ajax add to cart works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shortcode for a custom loop in a template however you should include the default shop loop action hooks which you can find in archive-product.php and markup using `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`

Something like this :

```
$products = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'  => array( 'product_variation' ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'attribute_pa_color',
                'value' => 'blue',
            )
        ),
    )
);

while( $products->have_posts() ) : 
       $products->the_post();
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );       
endwhile;
```